# Datamining Multithreading vs Multiprocessing

Tags: python, twisted, urllib3

I wrote and rewrote my little python application to a point where my current python skills aren't enough. I started with a single threaded application with Beautiful Soup as the parser, changed to lxml. Made the script multi-threaded, i discovered twisted but couldn't change this little snippet to twisted. I will just post this here so maybe you guys can point me to better directions to make this maybe a bit faster. To fetch 150k pages i need like 1 hour at this point. Iam happy with this cause i was 3x slower when i had my first attempt to write it.

```py
#! /usr/bin/python
# coding: ISO-8859-1
import time, PySQLPool, Queue, threading
from urllib3 import connection_from_url
from lxml import etree
import cStringIO as StringIO

headers = {   
           'User-Agent'         : 'Mozilla/4.77 [en] (X11; I; IRIX;64 6.5 IP30)',
           'Accept'             : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Language'    : 'en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
           'Accept-Encoding'    : 'gzip, deflate',
           'Accept-Charset'     : 'utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'
}

t = time.time()
PySQLPool.getNewPool().maxActiveConnections = 60
db = PySQLPool.getNewConnection(username='user', password='pass', host='127.0.0.1', db='fddb')
pool = connection_from_url('http://fddb.info/', maxsize=60, timeout=150, headers=headers)
detailCounter = 0
urls = {}
queue = Queue.Queue()
out_queue = Queue.Queue()

clean_rows = {
              "Brennwert":"details_brennwert",
              "Kalorien":"details_kalorien",
              "Protein":"details_protein",
              "Kohlenhydrate":"details_kohlenhydrate",
              "davon Zucker":"details_zucker",
              "davon Polyole":"details_polyole",
              "Fett":"details_fett",
              "Ballaststoffe":"details_ballaststoffe",
              "Broteinheiten":"details_broteinheit",
              "Alkohol":"details_alkohol",
              "Cholesterin":"details_cholesterin",
              "Koffein":"details_koffein",
              "Wassergehalt":"details_wasser",
              "Vitamin C":"details_vitc",
              "Vitamin A":"details_vita",
              "Vitamin D":"details_vitd",
              "Vitamin E":"details_vite",
              "Vitamin B1":"details_vitb1",
              "Vitamin B2":"details_vitb2",
              "Vitamin B6":"details_vitb6",
              "Vitamin B12":"details_vitb12",
              "Natrium":"details_natrium",
              "Eisen":"details_eisen",
              "Zink":"details_zink",
              "Magnesium":"details_magnesium",
              "Chlor":"details_chlor",
              "Mangan":"details_mangan",
              "Schwefel":"details_schwefel",
              "Kalium":"details_kalium",
              "Kalzium":"details_kalzium",
              "Phosphor":"details_phosphor",
              "Kupfer":"details_kupfer",
              "Fluor":"details_fluor"
              }

def rows_escape(text):
    for item, key in clean_rows.items():
        text = text.replace(item, key)
    text = text.rstrip()
    return text

clean_values = {
         "kJ"   :"",
         "kcal" :"",
         "g"    :"",
         "mg"   :"",
         "%"    :"",
         ","    :".",
         u"\u03bc": ""
         }

def values_escape(text):
    for item, key in clean_values.items():
        text = text.replace(item, key)
    text = text.rstrip()
    return text

def insertDetails(container, foods_id):
    c = PySQLPool.getNewQuery(db)
    query_rows = ''
    query_values = ''
    for item in container:
        query_rows += item['row'] + ','
        query_values += item['value'] + ','

    c.Query("INSERT INTO details (%sdetails_id,foods_id) VALUES (%sNULL,%s)" % (query_rows, query_values, foods_id))
    c.Query("UPDATE foods SET foods_check = '1' WHERE foods_id=%d" % (foods_id))

def getHP(url):
    r = pool.request('GET', '/' + url)
    return r.data

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            host = self.queue.get()
            data = getHP(host[0])
            self.out_queue.put([data, host[1]])
            self.queue.task_done()

class DatamineThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.out_queue = out_queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            global detailCounter

            qData = self.out_queue.get()
            data = qData[0]
            foods_id = qData[1]

            container = []
            parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='cp1252')
            tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(data), parser)
            divx = tree.xpath('//div[@style="background-color:#f0f5f9;padding:2px 4px;" or @style="padding:2px 4px;"]')

            for xdiv in divx:
                x = etree.ElementTree(element=xdiv, parser=parser)

                value = x.xpath('string(//div/text())')
                label = x.xpath('string(//*[self::a or self::span]/text())')

                label = rows_escape(label)

                if not "[nodata]" in value:
                    if u"\u03bc" in value:
                        value = values_escape(value)
                        item4 = 0
                        item4 = float(value)
                        item4 = item4 / 1000
                        container.append({'row':label,'value':str(item4)})
                    else:
                        container.append({'row':label,'value':values_escape(value)})

            detailCounter += 1
            container = tuple(container)
            insertDetails(container, foods_id)

            self.out_queue.task_done()

def main():

    c = PySQLPool.getNewQuery(db)
    c.Query("SELECT foods_id, foods_url FROM foods WHERE foods_check = 0")
    urls = c.record

    for i in range(6):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue, out_queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    for item in urls:
        queue.put([item['foods_url'], item['foods_id']])

    for i in range(6):
        dt = DatamineThread(out_queue)
        dt.setDaemon(True)
        dt.start()

    queue.join()
    out_queue.join()

main()
db.close
print "Zeit: %.2f New Details: %d" % (time.time()-t, detailCounter)
```

Comment: do dbfetch/memory/cputime profiling of your application and identify the real bottleneck before you blindly attempt to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the multiprocessing module if you have multiple CPUs AND if your program seems to be very CPU intensive. Python is notoriously bad with multithreading because of the Global Interpreter Lock, or GIL which basically ensures that on any given time, there can be only 1 python thread of execution in a single process.

Comment: Well i tried, multiprocessing & twisted. But somehow they where slower then my snipped that i posted there.

Comment: Ah also: bc either the url fetching or the cpu will be your bottleneck I suggest you do 2 * or 3 * number of cores of processes which in loop first will fetch an url and then process it. Any extra synchronization will surely kill you.